# Symfony inserts number (?port) into URL when redirects for authorization

Tags: symfony, heroku, authorization

Im using Symfony2 with the built in user authentication. I not using the FOSUser bundle.

On my local version, using apache, it all works fine.

On my live site, running ngnix on heroku, whenever symfony redirects for authorization reasons, a 5 digit number is inserted between the domain, and the path. For example

http://mywebsite.herokuapp.com:24956/api/login_form
OR
http://mywebsite.herokuapp.com:24956/api/users

This happens when redirecting 
(i) to the login page when accessing a URL behind the firewall
(ii) after successfully logging in
(iii) to the login page after failing to login and being redirected to the login page
(iv) to the login page after logout

So it appears to occur whenever symfony2 redirects related to authorization.

So far searches have revealed nothing!

Comment: yes this is the port number being added to your url :)

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by adding this to my config.yml:

```
framework:
router:
    http_port: 80
    https_port: 443
```

If you have other ports for http and https on your local dev environment you can use parameters for them.